# Show that Exists a Solution to a Differential Equation in $[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Show that the problem $y'=x^2+y^2,  y(0)=0$ has a solution in the section $[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]$.

Firstly, since $f(x)=x^2+y^2$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then in particular it's continuous in all rectangles $[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}]\times[-b,b]$ for all $b>0$. Also, in this square the maximum of $f_y(x,y)$ is $2b$. Therefore, according to the existence and uniqueness theorem exists a solution in $[-h,h]$, when $h=\min\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{b}{2b}\}=\min\{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{2}\}=\frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, exists a solution in $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$. Let $y_1=y(\frac{1}{2}), y_2=y(-\frac{1}{2})$.

From here, I'm still stuck. I though of saying that if $I$ is the maximal section in which exists a solution, then in particular, the solution $u$ is defined at $\pm \frac{1}{2}$ and satisfies $u'=x^2+u^2, u(\frac{1}{2})=y_1, u(-\frac{1}{2})=u_2$.

Here to solve these two problems (one for each condition), I used a rectangle again as I did earlier only for example around $(\frac{1}{2}, y_1)$, like so $[\frac{1}{2}-a, \frac{1}{2}+a]\times[y_1-b,y_1+b]$. Again I looked for the maximum $M$ of $|f_y(x,y)|$ in this rectangle, to say that the solution of the problem with the condition $u(\frac{1}{2})=y_1$ is defined in $[\frac{1}{2}-h,\frac{1}{2}+h]$ when $h=\min\{\frac{b}{M}, a\}$, but since at this time there were too many cases (I also had to do the same thing around $(-\frac{1}{2}, y_2)$ so this was double the work) to check, like for the values of $M$ and then for the values of $h$ given the value of $M$. It just seems to sloppy and not elegant to me.

Is there a way to get around this problem of the multiple cases for a more elegant solution?

Note: I'm trying to do this without finding the solution at all, and I just want to show that the solution exists in the interval $[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}].$

Comment: You may compare with the solution to $z'=1/2+z^2$, if this is among your available tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are supposed to do it using Picard iterations (and a contraction on a rectangle) then it works on the square $I\times I$ with $I=[-a,a]$ and $a=1/\sqrt{2}$. This is because
$$ M=\max\{x^2+y^2:x,y\in I\} = 1$$
so $y(t)=\int_0^t (x^2+y(x)^2) dx$ will map the set of graphs in the square into itself.
But the answer depends upon what method you are supposed to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the type of answer desired, but I'll just point out that this initial value problem does have a closed form solution in terms of Bessel functions:

$$ y = {\frac { \left( {{ J}_{-3/4}\left({x}^{2}/2\right)}-{{ Y}_{-3
/4}\left({x}^{2}/2\right)} \right) x}{-{{ J}_{1/4}\left({x}
^{2}/2\right)}+{{ Y}_{1/4}\left({x}^{2}/2\right)}}}
$$
which is continuous on the interval $(-a,a)$ where $a$ is the first positive
zero of the denominator, approximately $2.003147359$.